# How can I use an InputBox to rename an ActiveX command button caption?

Tags: excel, inputbox, vba

How can I use an `InputBox` to rename an ActiveX command button caption? I am using Excel VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub Test()
 ' change CommandButton1 to your Command Button name '
 ActiveSheet.CommandButton1.Caption = InputBox("Caption?")
End Sub
```